# How to debatch XML with multiple root nodes in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I am receiving a XML file with multiple root nodes like below.  I want to debatch this message in BizTalk.  I tried using Envelope schema but it's not working on XML with multiple root nodes.  Is there any other way to debatch this type of XML?  I want to avoid doing it in odx since the file coming in is very huge 100+MB.

```
<Xml_834_Dental>
  <G_1>
   ...
  </G_1>
</Xml_834_Dental>
<Xml_834_Dental>
  <G_1>
   ...
  </G_1>
</Xml_834_Dental>
<Xml_834_Dental>
  <G_1>
   ...
  </G_1>
</Xml_834_Dental>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Pipeline component that wraps a single root node around the payload (and possible add a namespace to existing root nodes), and then you can debatch as normal.